# Loop for subseting variable names into matrix

Tags: r, loops

I need to get variable names from my data frames to ensure they all are named the same. At first it looked simple, I used test code for two dfs:

```
x=rbind(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
```

And using example it looked like this:

```
VAR1 VAR2 VAR3
VAR1 VAR2 VARa
```

And `x` is considered as a `matrix`, which is very convenient.

But since there are many more dfs than two, looping is required so I wrote simple code:

```
varnames=0
for (i in 1:length(mylist){
varnames=rbind(colnames(get(mylist[i])))
}
```

Where `mylist` is list of my dfs names. Object `varnames` is a `matrix` but it has only one row... Could you provide me quickfix? I believe I am missing something simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call`

```
cn1 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc")
cn2 <- c("ab", "bb", "cc")
cn3 <- c("ab", "bc", "cc")

cnames <- list(cn1, cn2, cn3)

do.call(rbind, cnames)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "aa" "bb" "cc"
#[2,] "ab" "bb" "cc"
#[3,] "ab" "bc" "cc"
```

Or alternatively use `sapply` on a list of dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame(aa=runif(9), bb=runif(9), cc=runif(9))
df2 <- data.frame(ab=runif(9), bb=runif(9), cc=runif(9))
df3 <- data.frame(ab=runif(9), bc=runif(9), cc=runif(9))

dataframes <- list(df1, df2, df3)

sapply(dataframes, colnames)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,] "aa" "ab" "ab"
#[2,] "bb" "bb" "bc"
#[3,] "cc" "cc" "cc"
```

To do this from csv files not yet loaded

First creating example files

```
library(Hmisc)

df1 <- data.frame(aa=runif(9), bb=runif(9), cc=runif(9))
df2 <- data.frame(ab=runif(9), bb=runif(9), cc=runif(9))
df3 <- data.frame(ab=runif(9), bc=runif(9), cc=runif(9))

# create named list of data frames
dataframes <- llist(df1, df2, df3)

dir <- "dftest"
dir.create(dir)

# write data frames in list to individual csv files int specified directory
lapply(names(dataframes), function(x) {
    write.csv(dataframes[[x]], file=file.path(dir, paste0(x, ".csv")), 
    row.names=FALSE)
    })
```

Read csv files and get column names

```
# get the path of the csv files
filenames <- file.path(dir, list.files(dir, pattern="*.\\.csv$"))

# read csv files into a list and assign names
csv.list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
names(csv.list) <- sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(filenames))

# same as before
sapply(dataframes, colnames)
```

Comment: I tried to use your solutions, and replicate your examples. What i believe is the problem both `cnames` and `dataframes` are objects consisting entire objects you used (`dataframes` returns 3 random dfs). In my case `mylist` consists ONLY names of my dfs like: df1.csv, df2.csv...dfn.csv..

Comment: Ah, then you'll have to load the data first, using `read.csv`. I'll see if I can whip something up.